# Windows powershell messagebox using Ansible

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, ubuntu, ansible

I tried to create a task in ansible playbook using win_powershell module but everytime I run the playbook, the task is hanging. Does anyone have a solution ?
I`m pretty new to ansible.

Here is the yml file:

```
---
- name: notification
 hosts: windows
 become: false
 gather_facts: false
 tasks:

   - name: message
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
         script: |
           Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
           [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('message')
```

Comment: The task is hanging because the Messagebox is active. However it is not shown to the currently logged in user but for Session 0 - which means the MessageBox is not visible at all. If you go into Task Manager you can kill the underlying Powershell-process and your Playbook would continue.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the following modules might be more suitable than running a powershell command. You'd need to install the community modules for either of these.

The [community.windows.win_msg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_msg_module.html#ansible-collections-community-windows-win-msg-module) module.
Usage:

```
- name: Display message.
  community.windows.win_msg:
    msg: 'message'
```

Ansible also supports toast notifications via [community.windows.win_toast module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_toast_module.html#ansible-collections-community-windows-win-toast-module)

Comment: Thank you, Justin ! I voted your answer as helpful but it won`t display due that I`m too new to this site.